# EntityClass Downloading Speedup

Tags: geography, entity

Running this command. Trying to get all cities more than 1 million people in US.

```
EntityClass["City", {"Country" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
   "Population" -> GreaterThan[1000000 people]}] // EntityList
```

Running for more than an hour. Can it speed up, if I was repeatedly running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax for [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) `"People"`.  You must use [natural language input](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/FreeFormAndExternalInput.html) by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> and typing `1000000 People` into the input box.  Alternatively, you could explicitly type out a `Quantity` expression.

The following returns in less-than one second.

```
EntityClass["City", {"Country" -> Entity["Country", "UnitedStates"], 
   "Population" -> GreaterThan[Quantity[1000000, "People"]]}] // EntityList
```

> ```
> {Entity["City", {"SanJose", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"Dallas", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"SanDiego", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"SanAntonio", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"Philadelphia", "Pennsylvania", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"Phoenix", "Arizona", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"Houston", "Texas", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"Chicago", "Illinois", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"LosAngeles", "California", "UnitedStates"}], 
>  Entity["City", {"NewYork", "NewYork", "UnitedStates"}]}
> ```

Hope this helps.

PS: You can copy as plain text when copying special forms like entities to get a more concise paste.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The MMA tutorials don't point everything out, I guess. CTRL-= is new to me. Thank you.